# Two definitions of jQuery ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, document-ready, ready

I'm trying to debug a strange behaviour on a Wordpress site: the code inside the first occurence of `ready` seems not to happen. Because of several plugins installed, I see this in code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){   (function() {   ... })();});
</script>
```

Then later, nearly at the end of the page I see:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).on('ready post-load', easy_fancybox_handler );
</script>
```

**Does one definition or "ready" override the other or will both actions happen?**

Comment: what's the `strange behavior` ?

Comment: There should not be any problem, except maybe first, because ready is in ready...

Comment: @Loading.. : I added `the code inside the first occurence of ready seems not to happen`

Comment: @Ultrazz008 : sorry, I didn't get it, can you explain?

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function(){  })(); is triggering on ready, but there's inside  (function() { which also means on ready.. you need only one of these, not one in another..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [documented](http://api.jquery.com/ready/),

> When multiple functions are added via successive calls to this method, they run when the DOM is ready in the order in which they are added.

So setting a `ready` handler twice is fine.

However:

- The first one is missing a trailing `})` and should be a syntax error (which is probably why it does not execute).
- The second one uses the `jQuery(document).on('ready')` overload, which is deprecated:

  > There is also `$(document).on( "ready", handler )`, deprecated as of jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 3.0. Note that if the DOM becomes ready before this event is attached, the handler will not be executed.

Comment: @Basj Then it should work - and it does in a fiddle. Check that you call to jQuery after referencing the jquery file and that you don't have any errors in the console.